# Where can I have a genuine Ainu cultural experience in Hokkaido?

Tags: japan, culture, hokkaido, indigenous-peoples

During my next trip to Japan I may end up in Hokkaido. I've read something about this mysterious indigenous group called Ainu/Aynu/Aino/Ezo, but I must admit my understanding of the whole thing is rather limited right now.

What I wish to know is: is there such a thing like an authentic Ainu village/town/whole-region where Ainu people live according to their tradition, as opposed to something staged for tourists?

Edit: given the comments below I wish to specify better what I mean with the word 'authentic'.
Of course, I don't expect pristine landscapes and Ainu people living in blissful harmony with fluffy penguins (semi-quote) but I won't be surprised to find out there still are authentic villages in remote areas of Hokkaido where mass tourism is not an issue at all.

People are subject to tourist's attention (tourist coming from different countries, at least) everywhere, not only when they "made a conscious decision to live a traditional life". This doesn't actually mean anything. Indian people are surprisingly differents (in local customs) from Italians and Italians take a lot of pictures during their travels there, still the tourism isn't banned in India.

Comment: If it's truly authentic, they won't allow you to go there. Otherwise, it could not stay authentic. You'll have to be content with the staged stuff, just like all the other tourists.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I don't see why they shouldn't allow visits. Japanese life style is pretty different from African one, still you are able to visit without thinking that the whole Japan is a stage for African visitors. I don't actually get your point, but may very well be my fault.

Comment: If you had made a conscious decision to live a traditional life instead of a modern one, would you want groups of foreigners to come gawk at you and take pictures? People do not like being tourist attractions. They'll tolerate it only if it makes them money.

Comment: this discussion fits best in the chat :-)

Comment: I think "traditional" can mean "resisting total assimilation" among other things and not just "living in a cave" or "living in a protected reserve". I know I can visit people living traditional lives in Mongolia for instance where living in a yurt that moves seasonally even if they might wear baseball caps and own a motorbike or a rifle or even a TV. I see no reason something analagous might not exist in Hokkaido.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Rubbish. I live a truly authentic suburban Australian lifestyle and anybody is allowed to go there, even you. "Authentic" in these contexts just means "not fake or overdone stuff put on just for tourists".

Comment: I think the two questions and their answers should be merged. I was quite shocked by the stuff I read in answers and comments on the older question, plus a few nonsequiturs. I like the answer here better than the old answers, which don't even cover Nibutani.

Comment: @hippietrail this is true in many areas of the world. You can go to an Inuit fishing village in Alaska where they still use mostly traditional fishing methods but then load their catch into pickup trucks at the end of the day, then go to the community hall and do traditional dances.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: That's totally cool and totally what I'm interested in. Every group should have a right to self determination and it's of interest to no matter what path they determine for themselves.

Comment: Five years ago when I last came to Japan the responses to this question rather depressed me so I didn't visit any Ainu museum or village. But now I'm back in 2019 and a local friend introduced me to his Ainu friend who is a successful Ainu artist & musician. He is proudly Ainu and felt the Hokkaido museum's Ainu section is so good that he drove me there. Ainu have just received the most official recognition ever in 2019 and the government is renovating some museums in time for the Olympics. There is also a new Ainu-run guesthouse in Nibutani. I hope to visit soon and submit a full answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as Ainu culture "in the wild" in any amount in Japan. They were only [allowed to practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_people#Current_affairs) of their culture freely in 1997. Before that, their [language was banned](http://www.ainu-assn.or.jp/english/eabout08.html), their land seized and an active assimilation was in place to make them disappear and integrate 100% into the Japanese society. Today there is hardly anyone speaking their language fluently.

The different known subgroups have seen most of their [population disappear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_people#Subgroups). Their largest remaining group has formed the [Hokkaido Ainu Association](http://www.ainu-assn.or.jp/english/eabout01.html).

The current population of Ainu is less educated compared to the Japanese average and the Ainu population is (likely because of the lack of education) in need of money:

> The Current, Real Socioeconomic Conditions of the Ainu People
>
> ○ Presently, of Ainu people over the age of 55, only 60% are junior secondary school graduates as a result of needing to support their families.
>
> ○ The percent of people receiving welfare benefits in Hokkaido, after Osaka at 1.8 times greater than the national average, is 1.6 times greater than the national average.
>
> ○ The percentage of Ainu people attending college is at 17.4% less than the national average, which is at approximately 50%.

Your question tells me you are searching for Ainu people living in an Ainu village outside of non-Ainu Japanese towns. This does not exist, since they do not own their own territory, but are living among non-Ainu Japanese. So it is not possible to find see them "Live according to their tradition".

Due to the educational issue and and their financial situation (The Ainu association for example specializes in giving loans to needy people) they are not really in the position, geographically and financially to have their own area and money to live without making it a touristy place. The [only things](http://www.lake-akan.com/en/ainu/) that you [can see](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g1120904-d547351-Reviews-Shiraoi_Ainu_Musuem_and_Village-Shiraoi_cho_Shiraoi_gun_Hokkaido.html) today are as touristy as most other things in Japan.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your interpretations of those figures are borderline offensive.  Hokkaido has a population of 5.5 million, of whom maybe 20,000 (0.3%) identify as Ainu.  For better or worse, most Ainu are not an oppressed minority, since they've mixed with the Japanese for generations and have more or less fully assimilated into Japanese culture.  They *do* own land, in the same way that any other Japanese citizen can, and there was even a famous lawsuit spurred by their property rights vs dam construction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_people#Litigation

Comment: Kayano and Kaizawa's land was seized after a standard process of compulsory acquisition from an acknowledged landowner. Being Ainu had nothing to with it, and many ethnic Japanese also had their land seized.  Now, plenty of territory (arguably all of Hokkaido) was taken from the Ainu from c. 1400 to the late 1800s, but that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: this discussion is off-topic. I never intened to have a political debate. I simply stated that they don't have a special territory and amended my reply accordingly. downvote why you like, I will delete my reply above.

Comment: The first half of your answer is fine, but your lines about "highly uneducated" and "urgent need of money" are sensationalist and incorrect.  Yes, the Ainu are historically disadvantaged, poorer and less educated on *on average*, but they're *not* shunned landless squatters living outside society in shantytowns, begging for our handouts.

Comment: I think your answer here and your interpretation of what I wrote is just as or even more sensationalist than what I wrote. I am fine to have a factional discussion about how to word/write things, but your initial comments come across aggressive, defensive and not constructive. On top of this, you switch your point of disagreement across your comments. I am fine to revise the newly mentioned parts of the text, but I would hope for a more constructive way of doing this instead of what happened here, and even more so in chat than as comments.

Comment: @jpakotal, it seems that it's your interpretation, not uncovery's answer, that is sensational. Nobody would get the image of "shunned landless squatters living outside society in shantytowns" from what he wrote. Tone it down a bit, jeez.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that due to the assimilation and modernisation policies during the Meiji Era in Japan, the Ainu culture and traditions received a 'decisive blow'.

See the [Promotion of Ainu Culture article](http://www.mlit.go.jp/hkb/ainu_e.html) and [Ainu Museum information](http://www.ainu-museum.or.jp/en/study/eng01.html).

So it is very unlikely, and if enclaves did exist, they would be as Michael Borgwardt suggests, off limits to tourists.

It was only very recently, 2008, that the Ainu were officially recognised as indigenous people of Japan (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_people#Official_recognition)).  (I remember hearing that on the news when I lived in Tokyo at the time).

Answer (score 4):

The sad but true answer is **nowhere, really**.  While some 20,000 people in Hokkaido identify as Ainu, virtually all have more or less assimilated into Japanese society.  By some estimates there are less than a dozen native speakers of the language left, and the Ainu "villages" at [Shiraoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiraoi,_Hokkaido) and [Akan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akan,_Hokkaido) are tourist traps.

Probably the closest you can get is the hamlet of **Nibutani** (二風谷), home to the [Nibutani Ainu Culture Museum](http://www.town.biratori.hokkaido.jp/biratori/nibutani/) (site in Japanese only) and former home of outspoken Ainu activist [Shigeru Kayano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shigeru_Kayano).  Japan Today has a [good description](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2010/10/24/travel/savoring-the-joys-of-ainu-hospitality/#.U3GVgnIeGlg), which also mentions a few Ainu-run *minshuku* to stay at.  This is also where Kayano set up Japan's first Ainu language schools, although I'm not sure any are open to the public.

Comment: Thanks for the (sad) answer. Did you watch the video? Can you pick out where the place they are talking about where they say everybody is welcome, Ainu, Japanese, and foreigners?

Comment: I met a successful Ainu artist and musician two days ago through an old local friend. He speaks highly of Nibutani. He might've mentioned Shiraoi but I'm sure he didn't mention Akan. My impression is there's at least a small Ainu resurgeance right now. They've gained even more official recognition this year and Ainu sites are being upgraded for the olympics. Most interesting for me is that there is now [a guesthouse run by Ainu in Nibutani](http://nibutani-yanto.com) with dorm beds for 3000 yen. I hope to go there soon.